How to change direction from (left to right) into (right to left)?
When I print sentences in Arabic language and I run the code, it displays inversely.
I don't how to fix this problem and change the direction from (ltr) into (rtl), I'm still new at learning programming languages so could you teach me how to fix it?

I researched to find a code that change the direction but I couldn't find.

You need to provide more information please: Is this Windows or Linux, console application or Windows?

Your IDE terminal simply doesn't support Arabic text, not only the directionality but also letter shaping. Even if you reverse the string it will look totally wrong. You can do absolutely nothing about it. Try running your program in a different terminal, like Windows terminal (if on Windows) or konsole or gnome terminal (on Linux).

Can you please [edit] your question to indicate if either of the representation in source code or the one from the (VS Code? Add that tag, too, then!) terminal are correct. As a new user here, make sure you take the [tour] and read [ask]. That said, lots of code out there simply assumes that letters always go from left to right. Getting Arabic to render correctly, even more so in a mix with non-Arabic is far from trivial, so you will find lots of bugs, often not even in your own code.
